# Twig / Ajax Passing request with a Get methode

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, twig

I'm trying to use the Get methode to pass an Ajax request.
I've added an alert on my function request to be sure of the link but I have no alert !

My code is:

This is my html.twig view:

```
<a href="#" onclick="request( {{ path('mooniki_vote_acteur', { 'id' : 8 } ) }} );">Je valide !</a>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
function request(path) { 
alert(path);
var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
            alert(xhr.responseText); // Données textuelles récupérées
    }
};

xhr.open("GET", path, true);
xhr.send(null);
}
```

And when I put a string argument in the request function, I have the alert.

Thank.

Comment: What the generated HTML of this `a` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `path()` function in twig it will always output something like `/app_dev.php/...` for example. The problem now is that - if you pass the result as argument to a function - the function thinks it is a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression)

I spotted the error in my console (F12). In Chrome Developer Console it shows the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor

Which basically tells you that it is treated as RegExp. What you want is a string representation of your path. Therefore just do it like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="request(' {{ path('mooniki_vote_acteur', { 'id' : 8 } ) }} ');">Je valide !</a>
----------------------------/\-------------------------------------------------/\
```

Notice the `'...'` right after/before the opening/closing bracket.

For me it correctly outputs my path and I could do an AJAX Request with it.
Btw you gave yourself the hint for the solution because it works when you've used a string argument.